# How to substract two times written as hh:mm and display the result in a textview

Tags: java, android, datetime, format

I'm a beginner in java/android but I am trying to make an app. A user must type in a time like 13:45 and then the app should substrat ex. 00:30 minutes from that time. That gives the result 13:15.
I have tried many different things but it wont work.

I have somthing like this. (At this stage I've hardcoded two times)

```
    String time1 = "00:30";
    String time2 = "13:45";

SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
Date date1 = format.parse(time1);
Date date2 = format.parse(time2);
long result= date2.getTime() - date1.getTime(); 

String strLong = Long.toString(result);

textView4.setText(strLong);
```

I'm getting an error in the format.parse(time1) and format.parse(time2). Is this the right way to do this? Any help? Thanks

Comment: what error do you get? i don't see any problem with the code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Calendar` type.

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
Date date2 = format.parse(time2);

Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(date2);
cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, -30); //Subtract 30 Min

String strLong= format.format(cal.getTime());
textView4.setText(strLong);
```

Comment: Thanks but it's still not working. Again I get the error in format.parse(time2) call. It says "Unhandled exception type ParseException" I'm using Eclipse and target is API-level 7.

Comment: @cna - Sorry! I didn't get you. Can you please post exception trace in your post.

Comment: I managed to figure it out. I needed a try/catch around the format.parse(time2). Then it worked! - Thanks for helping me.

Comment: @cna - Yes! you have to catch or re-throws this *checked* ParseException.